# Finite cylider is not compact ? ,Gauss bonnet Thm

Tags: differential-geometry

In Topology or geometry, I know that definition of compact surface is boundary and closed . 
 finite cylinder is compact. furthermore cylinder is oriented And genus of cyliner is one.

Q1. For compute euler characteristic of Cylinder , Can i use 2(1-g) ?
Q2. So, I try to solve integral total Kg of cylinder . Can i use Gauss-bonnet thm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\chi(S) = 2 - 2g(S)$ works only for compact surface without boundary. But here you can use that a cylinder is homeomorphic to a disk minus another disk and this is easy to compute the Euler characteristic.

You need then to compute the Gauss curvature $K$ on the cylinder (which is constant) and you will get $\int_{\partial C} k_g = 2\pi \chi(C) - \int_C K dA $ where $C$ is your cylinder.